# What are the parameters for .GetWindow function in python?

Tags: python, process, window, pywin32

I'm kinda new to programming, and I wanna write a simple program that needs to OCR a particular window. Currently, I'm using (w.GetForegroundWindow()), but that gets me the current window which would always be the Python shell, since that is the one that is active when I run it, even if it is for a split second only.

After searching around for a bit, I found the .Getwindows function, but not much of it on Python. What does it do, and what are the parameters? Will i be able to target a particular process (=window) with it? If not, what can I use then?

This is using the pywin32 module on Python 2.7 in Windows

---

I'm in Windows, Python 2.7 . The GetWindows function comes with the module pywin32, if im not wrong

Comment: You need to explain more about this function. What module does it come from? What OS? What version of Python? It sounds like you might be talking about Windows + IronPython, is that right?

Comment: nop, not that.  included all that in the edited summary already. Thnx btw

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to call `EnumWindows` with a callback and then get information about each hwnd - for example name, title or window class. Check that against what you are looking for and save the matched hwnd. After `EnumWindows` returns, check that you found a valid hwnd and use that for your program.

It's not pleasant - there's not much support for this kind of thing in windows. I've heard that using accessibility features is better but I have no experience using that.

Comment: ouch, sounds a little complicated. So that would allow me to target that specific program using the hwnd right?

Comment: it would allow you to get a specific hwnd. not sure what you mean by program in this context. if you know the name of the process, perhaps you could try `EnumProcesses` and get the main hwnd from the processinfo structure